# Designing generic algorithms in C#

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

I'm writing some 2D/3D geometry library code.

In this example let's consider a `Contain` method that checks if a `Line` is entirely inside a collection of `Box`s.  I have both 2D and 3D implementations of each object.

The method signatures would look something like this:

- `static bool Contains(List<Box3> boxes, Line3 line)    // 3D implementation`
- `static bool Contains(List<Box2> boxes, Line2 line)    // 2D implementation`

These two methods are very similar, the only differences are we are either working with the type set `(Point2, Line2, Box2)` or `(Point3, Line3, Box3)`.  For reference, my `Point` and `Line` classes are structs.

So I tried something that looks like this:

```
static bool Contains<TB, TL, TP>(List<TB> boxes, TL line) 
    where TB: IAxisAlignedBox
    where TL: ILineSegment
    where TP: IPoint
```

The main issue with this is internally I am calling another function, one of the following:

- `Point2 Intersect(Box2 box, Line2 line)    // 2D implementation`
- `Point3 Intersect(Box3 box, Line3 line)    // 3D implementation`

As explained to me in another question this won't work in C#, because it will only call `TP Intersect(TB box, TL line)`, which is not specialized.

So my question is ... how am I supposed to write this algorithm generically, without using `dynamic`?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] demonstratng the problem (probably stick to the 2D as it'll be easier)

Comment: How about make an IContainer and implement both 3D and 2D type of data. You may hide logic inside of your `bool Contains( IContainer container)`, where `container` might have 3D or 2D data.

Comment: if `Intersect` isn't generic, then its not worth the hassle

Comment: Do you have control over the points, boxes and lines classes? Can you show the implementation of `Contains` and `Intersect`?

Comment: @Sweeper I have control over everything, it is a library that I am writing for work.

Comment: @Luaan I simply want some functions that could be use to test if a line is in a bunch of boxes.  There will be other contain functions for other types of 2D/3D geometry. Sometimes the 2D/3D implementations will be different, other times they will be very similar.

Comment: Once again if you show us some real code, with real implementation (say just for the 2D) I'm fairly sure it can be made generic to work with 3D too. But at the moment this question is too abstract to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid C# generics just don't work that way. There is no duck-typing, and you don't really get a different generic type for each type argument. All the type resolution happens at compile-time, and doesn't care about the actual type of the type argument. To get runtime type resolution, you need to use `dynamic`, with all its pains.

The alternatives depend a lot on what your requirements are. For example, if you have full control over the types that can be used in the `Contains` methods, you can do your own type resolution:

```
if (box is Box2 box2 && line is Line2 line2) return Contains(box2, line2);
else if (box is Box3 box3 && line is Line3 line3) return Contains(box3, line3);
```

This is probably the *fastest* thing you can do (besides just having a specific implementation for each case in the first place). If you're looking for something with less maintanance, you can make use of delegates:

```
static bool ContainsImpl<TB, TL, TP>(List<TB> boxes, TL line, Func<TB, TL, bool> intersect)
{
  DoAllTheStuff();
  if (intersect(box, line)) ...
}

public static Contains(List<Box2> boxes, Line2 line)=> ContainsImpl(boxes, line, Intersect);
public static Contains(List<Box3> boxes, Line3 line)=> ContainsImpl(boxes, line, Intersect);
```

The generic method contains the common logic for doing `Contains`, and delegates all the specific stuff based on the actual types (any user of your library would use the non-generic methods). The main benefit is that you get full type checking this way - you can't accidentally forget a pattern matching case for a new type you added. This is probably not worth the overhead of the delegate, though, given how simple the intersect method is. You need to think about the users of your library.

In some cases, inverting everything and using a pull-model (e.g. through `IEnumerable<TB>`) instead of pushing can be worthwhile. But again, all of that is a call you must make based on your actual requirements. And of course, you can always use code generation - sometimes there just isn't a good way to represent a pattern in C#, and things like T4 templates can help considerably.

In general, C# generics are, well, generic. If the generic type constraints are not enough for what `Contains` need to do, there's little point in making it generic. You can still use it to avoid unnecessary code repetition, it's great for run-time generated types and applying delegates, but it can't ever do more than the type constraints allow without explicit casting (or `dynamic`). They're not C++ templates and they don't change C# into Python or Scala.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Could you expand a bit on what you mean by using a pull-model?

Comment: @woggy It's a bit tricky to explain without a good concrete example :) The basic idea is that instead of repeatedly calling the delegate, you would call a method that operates on e.g. `IEnumerable<Box2>` once - the control is inverted. You can use `yield return` to have C# turn your iterator method into a state machine that is executed by the caller, on its own terms. This approach is used extensively in LINQ, for example.